# How to replace Swagger's enum with a link to a resource?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, dropwizard, jsonschema

I know from [the documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apimodelproperty) that I can annotate my POJOs like this:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "pet status in the store", allowableValues = "available,pending,sold")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }
```

to produce something like:

```
"properties": {
        ...,
        "status": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "pet status in the store",
          "enum": [
            "available",
            "pending",
            "sold"
          ]
        }
      }
```

Image now to implement the method:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "pets in the store")
public Set<String> getPets() {
    return pets;
  }
```

which returns a list of pets available in the store. For example, one day it could be `["cats", "dogs", "songbirds"]` and then just `["cats", "dogs"]` when the songbirds get sold out.

My API would in fact have an endpoint to fetch the list of pets:

http://petShop.foo/pets

Instead of using `allowableValues = "cats, dogs, songbirds"`,
I would like to specify with a Swagger annotation that
that field must contain a value returned by the given endpoint. That is, something like:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "pets in the store", allowableValues = "/pets")
public Set<String> getPets() {...}
```

This in order to allow my client/front-end to know which values can be use when making a request to,
for example, buying a pet online. Exactly how I could do if I had `"enum": ["cats", "dogs", ..]`

Answer (score 2):

You may do the following:

- Fork [Swagger](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core)
- Extend method `processAllowedValues` in `io.swagger.util.ParameterProcessor` class to consume an Enum class in addition to comma separated values. (currently it supports only comma separated values and range)
- Use your custom variant of Swagger while building your web application

However, with this method, you'll need to continue maintaining your fork of Swagger.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, however +1 for the effort. It looks like Swagger currently does not support what I need. To fork Swagger would be a solution, with the drawback you explained.

Comment: @Niccolò Your's is not a "problem", it's a "feature ask" :D

Comment: That's true! When I wrote the question I still thought I might have missed something in the documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

A Java annotation is a syntactic metadata. It gets processed during compilation and (if it has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` is specified on it) is available during runtime for *reflective* access. Hence, there is no direct way of resolving or setting  during runtime!

However, there is a way in Java to accomplish what you want - but it's a bit too complex (and uses some undocumented features!). Here is how:

- Create a custom annotation ApiModelProperty(one with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.COMPILE)`) - this would act as a wrapper for `@ApiModelProperty`
- Write an annotation processor class for above annotation (it must extend from `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` class)
- In your annotation processor, *inject* `@ApiModelProperty` with values as read from your `Enum` (this part is fairly complex as you need to traverse through the AST of `Enum` to get allowed values)

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) is a good example. It manipulates Java's *Abstract Syntax Tree* to add new features in Java.

In [it's source code](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok), under `lombok.javac.handlers`, take a look at:

- `HandleConstructor.addConstructorProperties` method to understand how to add annotations in compile time. (using `com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCAnnotation`)
- `HandleVal.visitLocal` method to understand how to read *literal* values.

You can also take a look at this tutorial: [Creating Custom Transformations](http://notatube.blogspot.in/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html)

Comment: I don't need to resolve the annotation at runtime: I'd rather like Swagger to read an annotation that contains an endpoint address from which the clients can retrieve the possible value for a field. Your approach, if I understand correctly, is an attempt to generate the enum list at runtime. Though interesting, it's not exactly what I'd need (1- at least as complex as a new swagger annotation to implement 2- what about the static version of the swagger.json schema?).

Comment: @Niccolò "Your approach, if I understand correctly, is an attempt to generate the enum list at runtime". the approach I suggested generates `allowedValues` at compile time, not runtime.